# Joint Probability Mass

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a die rolled 10 times and $A$ represents number of times '1' occur and $B$ represent number of times '3' occur.
I'm not able to get the joint Probability Mass function.

My best effort :
$P_{A,B} (i,j) = {10\choose i} {{10-i}\choose j} p^{i+j}$

I'm not getting how to calculate $p$ for both points $i$ and $j$ and I don't know if the combination expression is right either. So, could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would divide this into cases because the analysis should vary.

1. **Case 1**, $P(0,0)$ is the easiest: $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{10}$.
2. **Case 2**, $P(i,j)$ where only $i=0$ (similarly for $j$):

   Normalize the following by $6^{10}$: ${10\choose j}\times 4^{10-j}$. You pick $j$ positions for the $3$'s. For the remaining, you pick any of the $4$ valid options ($1$ is not allowed).
3. **Case 3**, where neither $i$ nor $j$ is $0$ but $(i+j)\leq10$:

   Normalize the following by $6^{10}$: ${10\choose j}\times {{10-j}\choose{i}} \times 4^{10-j-i}$.  You could do $10\choose i$ first and the answer would be the same.
4. **Case 4**, when $i+j>10$, again easy because then $P(i,j)=0$.

You may note that Case 3 actually subsumes Case 2 but I think it's easier to break it down this way. I've assumed a fair die, an unfair die could make it a bit messy.

Comment: For some i, j: could it be like: Choosing i places from 10, j places from 10-i, and for other 10-i-j places, we have, 4 alternatives for each place and the sample space is 6 raised to 10. So, like (10ci) (10-icj) (4^10-i-j) whole divided by 6^10?

Comment: Correct, that is Case 3 in my answer.

Comment: (10ci) (10-icj) (4^10-i-j) whole divided by 6^10?

Comment: Whoops, I switched the positions. let me fix that, good catch.

Comment: Oh, so did you mean divide by 6^10 when you said "Normalize"?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if that wasn't obvious. Typically in cases like this I like to count the explicit number of cases because that's just easier when you have a uniform distribution (like in a fair die). The total number of outcomes is just the size of the sample space so you divide by that.

Comment: Yeah, got it! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer so that the question may be marked closed!